# Docker Compose Mounting Volume Error: No Such File or Directory

Tags: docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker

I am trying to build a simple Drupal container using docker-compose, but I'm getting an error when trying to mount the named volume. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    web:
        build: ./build
        image: "myrmidon16/drupal-base:latest"
        working_dir: "/var/www/html"
        volumes:
            - sites:/var/www/html/sites
        links:
            - "db"
        ports:
            - 8001:80
    db:
        image: "mysql:latest"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal-base
        volumes:
            - ".:/var/www/html"
        ports:
            - "3306"
    drush:
        image: "mparker17/mush"
        working_dir: "/var/www/html"
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        links:
            - "db"

volumes:
    sites:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: bind
            o: bind
            device: ${PWD}/sites
```

But when I run `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error, even though the directory exists:

`ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: error while mounting volume with options: type='bind' device='/mnt/f/Documents/sites' o='bind': no such file or directory`

I'm running Docker for Windows Edge (18.05.0-ce-rc1) on Windows 10 Pro with Compose v 1.21.0. I'm also sharing the F drive through Docker for Windows.

Please let me know if you need any additonal information. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, local driver does not support any options.
So in your docker-compose options `o:bind` is invalid.

According to: Documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options

Comment: is it possible to use other drivers to circumvent the problem? what's recommended for Windows users?

Comment: if this correctly identifies the problem, then what is the solution?

Comment: Not to use named volumes, and just use bind mounts.

Comment: Just to add, type should also be set to "none" in order for this to work

Answer (score 2):

It does work on Windows, but you have to add a leading slash to the `device` option, e.g.

```
docker volume create \
            --opt type=none \
            --opt o=bind \
            --opt device=/$(pwd)/grafana/dashboards \
            --name grafana_dashboards
```

Comment: In that example you are not changing anything from it's default values.

Answer (score -1):

On Windows you should not create volume in the volume section. The one in service is enough to create a mounth to the Windows file system, as long as it is enabled in:
Docker->Settings->Shared Drives - the whole drive
and make sure you click the "Reset credentials" if you change windows password

The path c:\Temp\some_dir works and the current directory notation(.) I am not sure.